# Criar código de barras com imagecreate e html

Tags: php

Tenho uma página que monta um código de barras, quero saber como fazer para ao invés da página retornar um html, ela retornar uma imagem.

Exemplo de como esta minha página:

```
<?php

$fino = 1;
$largo = 3;
$altura = 50;
$text = null;

$barcodes[0] = '00110';
$barcodes[1] = '10001';
$barcodes[2] = '01001';
$barcodes[3] = '11000';
$barcodes[4] = '00101';
$barcodes[5] = '10100';
$barcodes[6] = '01100';
$barcodes[7] = '00011';
$barcodes[8] = '10010';
$barcodes[9] = '01010';

for ($f1 = 9; $f1 >= 0; $f1--) {
    for ($f2 = 9; $f2 >= 0; $f2--) {
        $f = ($f1 * 10) + $f2;
        $texto = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $texto .= substr($barcodes[$f1], ($i - 1), 1) . substr($barcodes[$f2], ($i - 1), 1);
        }
        $barcodes[$f] = $texto;
    }
}

$text .= '<img src="../Img/p.gif" style="width: ' . $fino . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img src="../Img/b.gif" style="width: ' . $fino . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img src="../Img/p.gif" style="width: ' . $fino . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img src="../Img/b.gif" style="width: ' . $fino . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img ';

// Recebe os dados
$texto = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'linha', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

if ((strlen($texto) % 2) <> 0) {
    $texto = '0' . $texto;
}

while (strlen($texto) > 0) {
    $i = round(substr($texto, 0, 2));
    $texto = substr($texto, strlen($texto) - (strlen($texto) - 2), (strlen($texto) - 2));

    if (isset($barcodes[$i])) {
        $f = $barcodes[$i];
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i += 2) {
        if (substr($f, ($i - 1), 1) == '0') {
            $f1 = $fino;
        } else {
            $f1 = $largo;
        }

        $text .= 'src="../Img/p.gif" style="width: ' . $f1 . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
        $text .= '<img ';

        if (substr($f, $i, 1) == '0') {
            $f2 = $fino;
        } else {
            $f2 = $largo;
        }

        $text .= 'src="../Img/b.gif" style="width: ' . $f2 . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
        $text .= '<img ';
    }
}
$text .= 'src="../Img/p.gif" style="width: ' . $largo . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img src="../Img/b.gif" style="width: ' . $fino . 'px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
$text .= '<img src="../Img/p.gif" style="width: 1px; height: ' . $altura . 'px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;">';



$img = imagecreate(410, 55);

// Transparent background
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);

// Red text
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
imagestring($img, 5, 0, 0, $text, $red);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a biblioteca https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator, se estiver usando composer basta instalar na pasta do teu projeto:

```
composer require picqer/php-barcode-generator
```

Gerando um `.png`:

```
$barcodes = '000101010100010';

$generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$generated = $generator->getBarcode($barcodes, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128);
```

Outros formatos:

- SVG: `$generated = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorSVG();`
- JPEG: `$generated = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG();`
- HTML: `$generated = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML();`

Tipos de códigos aceitos: https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator#accepted-types

---

Alternativamente você pode usar o [TCPDF](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) (o php-barcode é baseado nele) seguindo os exemplos de https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/tree/master/examples/barcodes, não é necessário composer, basta baixar o TCPDF pelo repositório e fazer o `include`, assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'tcpdf_barcodes_1d_include.php';

$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode('http://www.tcpdf.org', 'C128');

// exibe no navegador a imagem
$barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(2, 30, array(0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar o `html2ps` é a solução que conheço para gerar uma imagem do seu html.

```
 html2ps index.html index.ps 
 convert index.ps index.png
```

Vai precisar instalar em seu servidor e executar com `exec` em background mas é uma solução a se pensar.

Pode obter aqui [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html)

Existe essa classe aqui também, ela facilita muito para escrever o código de barras em formato de imagem [Classe Código de barras](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2176-PHP-Web-interface-to-generate-barcode-images.html)

Comment: Entendo, é uma solução mas quero uma coisa bem simples com o código que postei.

Comment: Outra solução é escrever tudo com GD do php.

Comment: Mas como vou colocar outras imagens? Com se trata de um código de barras que é montado a padres de 2 imagens gif. Tem algum exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: @HugoBorges O mais fácil é desenhar as barras do código uma por uma com [imagerectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php), na mesma lógica que você usa pra montar o HTML.